# Finding and replacing strings with certain character patterns in array

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a pretty large database with some data listed in this format, mixed up with another bunch of words in the *keywords* column.

**BA 093**, **RJ 342**, **ES 324**, etc.

The characters themselves always vary but the structure remains the same. I would like to change all of the strings that obey this character structure : *2 characters A-Z*, *space*, *3 characters 0-9* to the following:

**BA-093**, **RJ-342**, **ES-324**, etc.

Be mindful that these strings are mixed up with a bunch of other strings, so I need to isolate them before replacing the empty space. Here is a sample string:

`Km 111 aracoiaba Araçoiaba sp 270 spvias vias sao paulo  Araçoiaba Bidirecional`

**sp 270** is the bit we want to change.

*EDIT: There was also an exception which should ignore the condition in case KM are the first two characters, it was handled by one of the answers*

I have written the beginning of the script that picks up all the data and shows it on the browser to find a solution, but I'm unsure on what to do with my *if* statement to isolate the strings and replace them. And since I'm using explode it is probably turning the data above into two separate arrays each, which further complicates things.

```
<?php

require 'includes/connect.php';

$pullkeywords = $db->query("SELECT keywords FROM main");

while ($result = $pullkeywords->fetch_object()) {

    $separatekeywords = explode(" ", $result->keywords);
    print_r ($separatekeywords);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is an example of one `$result->keywords`?  `BA 093, RJ 342, ES 324` or just `BA 093`???

Comment: I have updated the question. `Km 111 aracoiaba Araçoiaba sp 270 spvias vias sao paulo  Araçoiaba Bidirecional` is an example of the string I'm working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should do it.

```
([A-Z]{2})\h(\d{3})
```

That says any character between `A-Z` two times (`{2}`). A horizontal white space `\h`. Then three `{3}` numbers `\d`. The `(` and `)` capture the values you want to capture. So `$1` and `$2` have the found values.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nU2yN0/1

PHP Usage:

```
$string = 'BA 093, RJ 342, ES 324';
echo preg_replace('~([A-Z]{2})\h(\d{3})~', '$1-$2', $string);
```

Output:

> BA-093, RJ-342, ES-324

You may want `(?:^|\h)([A-Z]{2})\h(\d{3})` which would require the capital letters don't have  text running into them. For example `AB 345, cattleBE 123, BE 678`. With this regex `cattleBE 123` wouldn't be found. Not sure what your intent with this example is though so I'll leave that to you..

The `?:` makes the `()` non capturing there. The `^` is so the capital letters can be the start of the string. The `|` is `or` and the `\h` is another horizontal space. You could do `\s` in place of `\h` if you wanted to allow new lines as well.

Update:

```
(?!KM)([A-Z]{2})\h(\d{3})
```

This will ignore strings starting with `KM`. https://regex101.com/r/nU2yN0/2

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I'll try it out now. But in case I want to make a modified copy of the values instead of replacing them directly, how would I do it?

Comment: Also, I ran into some trouble: the space from the other *keywords* were also being removed and I need to add an exception. I want the pattern to be ignored if the first two characters start with "KM'. 

I apologize for the complications, I am only running into them now.

Comment: Okay then add `(?!KM)` to `([A-Z]{2})\h(\d{3})` so `(?!KM)([A-Z]{2})\h(\d{3})`. https://regex101.com/r/nU2yN0/2 What do you mean `the space from the other keywords were also being removed and I need to add an exception`. Are you using that explode still?

Comment: Let me get an example directly from the database so I can make this easier: `Km 111 aracoiaba Araçoiaba sp 270 spvias vias sao paulo  Araçoiaba Bidirecional`. We want to add a `sp-270` next to the `sp 270`. What's the best way to implement the REGEX you suggested?

Comment: Those aren't capital letters you could make it case insensitive, put an `i` after the delimiter (`~`). If that is what you want, that makes this open to more matches though.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give regex a bigger read. This is the only time I've ever had to use it.